# Is there a way to map plugin specific keys to do multiple keys in Vim?

Tags: vim, mapping, shortcut, nerdtree

I'd like to map NERDTree's tab opening key, 't', to do multiple things. Namely, I'd like it to open the tab then do the following list of commands: TlistToggle Ctrl W, Ctrl T, Ctrl W, Shift K, 30, Ctrl W, minus-sign. So that I open the taglist for the file, then horizontally split the list and the file, then resize the tag list.

I've tried the following:

```
nnoremap <t> NERDTree-t TlistToggle <C-W><C-T><C-W><S-K>30<C-W> -
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything.

Thoughts? Am I just completely doing this wrong. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final solution I used to open a file in new tab from NERDTree and then split and resize the file & TlistToggle:

```
autocmd FileType nerdtree nnoremap <buffer> t :call nerdtree#ui_glue#invokeKeyMap("t")<CR> :TlistToggle<CR> <C-w><C-t><C-w>K :exe "resize " . ((winheight(0) + winheight(1)) * 3/20)<CR>
```

And this resizes the tag list that was opened in a horizontal tab by 15% of the total amount of lines in the whole window.

Answer (score 2):

- The NERDTree mapping is not a global one, but only exists (and makes sense) in the plugin's sidebar. That makes it more difficult to override, but you can hook into NERDTree setting its `'filetype'`, and then define a *buffer-local* mapping to override NERDTree's:

  :autocmd FileType nerdtree nnoremap  t ...
- While *normal* mode commands (like the `<C-w>...` stuff) can indeed be concatenated, that's not true for the plugin invocations. You can find out NERDTree's via `:nmap <buffer> t`:

  :call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("t")

The Taglist's is also an Ex command; you can combine both with `|` (written as `<Bar>` in mappings):

```
:call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("t")<Bar>TlistToggle<CR>
```

So, something like this should work (I didn't test it):

```
:autocmd FileType nerdtree nnoremap <buffer> t :call nerdtree#invokeKeyMap("t")<Bar>TlistToggle<CR><C-W><C-T><C-W>K30<C-W>-
```

Comment: What's the problem? Try building this command by (concatenated) command.

Comment: The problem is that nothing happens. Is there a way to enable some kind of verbose error output?

Comment: I used 'verb map t' in the nerdtree panel and it gave me this: "*@:call <SNR>12_openInNewTab(0)<CR>". Do I need to override that particular call in the nerdtree.vim or is there a way to override it in the .vimrc? Or perhaps a way to escalate my autocmd above nerdtree's?

Comment: The problem was nerdtree had an update where "nerdtree#invokeKeyMap" was changed to "nerdtree#ui_glue#invokeKeyMap"

Comment: Good to see you've found a solution, and posted that. You could at least upvote my answer to give some appreciation, though.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Thanks for all your help :) You had the real solution, I just had to tweak for versioning.